# org.apache.sling.api.resource,version=[2.3,3) -- Cannot be resolved

Tags: java, aem, sling

Hi I am not able to access content of my project, I have uploaded all the packages which are required to access content from CQ. Only thing I can see is

> org.apache.sling.api.resource,version=[2.3,3) -- Cannot be resolved

Can this be the reason for exception and if yes please let me know how to resolve it.

CQ version 5.6

Comment: are you saying when you go to siteadmin you don't see the content? If yes, does your package installation works fine when you upload your package? 
The error looks as if CQ is looking for jar in your system and is unable to find so. Check if you have that jar, if not then do a build and if you are connected to net, maven will download the dependency if mentioned as a dependency in pom file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message means that the OSGi framework is unable to supply a version >= 2.3 and < 3 of the `org.apache.sling.api.resource` Java package for a bundle B that wants to import it.

As a result, bundle B cannot be activated, and parts of your system won't work.

Looking at the webconsole (under `/system/console` by default in Sling and CQ) you can see that this package is provided by the `org.apache.sling.api bundle`, so either you have an old version of that bundle in your system, or you have installed incompatible bundles that require a newer version of that package.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the missing package by explicilty importring it. Accecess the pom.xml file in the core folder of your project  *core/pom.xml* and list the dependency under *Import-Package*

```
<configuration>
    <bnd><![CDATA[
        Import-Package: 
            javax.annotation;version=0.0.0,
            org.apache.sling.api.servlets;version="[2.3,3)",*
     ]]></bnd>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check version of org.apache.sling.api.resource in package-info.class file in org.apache.sling.api.resource package in uber-jar.

[image]

You might have version between 2.3 and 3. Try installing lower version uber-jar that has package version <2.3