# AEM Cannot be resolved for some libs

Tags: build, aem, crx

Adobe CQ5, Version 5.5.0

```
com.day.cq.commons,version=[5.7,6) -- Cannot be resolved
com.day.cq.commons.jcr,version=[5.7,6) -- Cannot be resolved
com.day.cq.dam.api,version=[1.2,2) -- Cannot be resolved
com.day.cq.replication,version=[5.15,6) -- Cannot be resolved
com.day.cq.wcm.api,version=[1.2,2) -- Cannot be resolved
com.day.cq.wcm.api.components,version=[5.7,6) -- Cannot be resolved
com.day.cq.wcm.api.designer,version=[5.7,6) -- Cannot be resolved
org.apache.sling.api,version=[2.3,3) -- Cannot be resolved
org.apache.sling.api.resource,version=[2.5,3) -- Cannot be resolved
org.apache.sling.api.wrappers,version=[2.5,3) -- Cannot be resolved
org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler,version=[2.3,3) -- Cannot be resolved
```

For example:

i uses `org.apache.sling.api <version>2.7.0</version>` in pom.xml and see this error `org.apache.sling.api,version=[2.3,3) -- Cannot be resolved` -

I found simular [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278236/org-apache-sling-api-resource-version-2-3-3-cannot-be-resolved) and if follow next answer I'm doing everything right - but I have same errors

> The error message means that the OSGi framework is unable to supply a
>   version >= 2.3 and < 3 of the org.apache.sling.api.resource Java
>   package for a bundle B that wants to import it.

Does anyone know how to fix these errors?

Comment: I was having the same issue with the **org.apache.sling.api,version=[2.10,3)** not getting resolved. I was using the latest and greatest version 2.16.0 of **org.apache.sling.api**. Since then I have down versioned to 2.9.0 and it works well in AEM 6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you use too fresh version of `org.apache.sling.api`. Because on CQ 5.6.1 `<version>2.4.3-R1488084-B001</version>` is used for this bundle.

I would suggest you to do next:

Check Sling/AEM dependencies you have in your POM file with Dependency Finder (you can find it there /system/console/depfinder). Just put there artifactId/package and it will provide you with correct Maven dependency.

For example for me it looks like this
[image: Dependency finder]

Comment: but i still have errors for com.day.cq.wcm.api
This libs include like %><%@taglib prefix="cq" uri="http :// www.day.com/taglibs/cq/1.0" %><%

Comment: @Maria what do you have in your POM file for com.day.cq.wcm.api?

Comment: @Maria also is it missing dependency from your bundle?

Comment: Actually, I installed new version CQ6 - and my problem was resolved